# validator does not work when trying to login and the field is empty

Tags: flutter, dart

[Codes Link Github](https://github.com/mrshahen/test)

I don't have any problems in the editor but the validator does not work when trying to login and the field is empty

Comment: This question could use a [repro]. Check out [ask] to improve this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue I fouded is that the `validate` argument in your `defaultFormField` is not working.

In your ***components.dart*** file :

- You are declaring the following argument: (Line 28)

```
required Function validate,
```

- You are calling this argument like this: (Line 43 to 45)

```
validator: (value){
  validate(value);
},
```

***The issue*** is that the value of your callback in the `validator` function is not returned. So the validator cannot work. So you need to do the following :

- Return the value of the callback

```
validator: (value){
  return validate(value);
},
```

- Modify the declaration of your argument

```
required String? Function(String?) validate,
```